# New iTunes Connect in-app purchases section not visible

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, submission, in-app

I'm having trouble submitting my game. I have paid and free applications contract, I have all in-app purchases in waiting for review status, but I'm still not seeing the In-app Purchases section under the main tab (under Builds). I've tested the in-app products via sandbox users and it works. As far as I know when I'm submitting for the first time I need to submit all in-apps with this build, but I don't see the in-app section under Build section. I've tried to submit it that way and got rejected as expected.

p.s. I needed art is in place and the button "Submit for review" is visible

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean once the "in-apps" are in Ready For Submit Status the "In-app Purchases Section" will be visible?

Comment: UPDATE I've edited the in-apps and their status became waiting for review, after one day they got rejected - returned to Developer Action Needed status with statement "We have returned your IAP product/s to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the IAPs with the binary. " I don't get it, if I submit the game as it is right now (but in-apps edited so they are in Waiting for Review status) game will be rejected as last time, on the other hand If I want to add the in-apps to the build they need to be in ready to submit status...

Comment: I am facing the exactly same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the In App Purchases section under the Builds in iTunesConnect.

Apple provides the reason for the rejection, kindly share it, as it help us better to solve your issue.

Comment: Game was rejected because it crashes on in app purchase attempt. I guess it logical since no in-apps were associated with the build. Note- Soomla plugin for Unity is used and all test purchases works + actual purchases on Google Play also works.

Comment: My app got rejected first time, and now after fixing issues, I am resubmitting app but not able to see inapp puchase menu in itunes submission, also inapp showing. Any help will be appreciated!!